# How to prevent overflow of background color of tr into disabled input field

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have table with rows that have background colors alternating between white and yellow. The cells contains input fields which in certain circumstances can be disabled. I use following styling to disable the field.

```
input.disabled {
   cursor: default;
   opacity: 0.4;
   filter: alpha(opacity=40);
   pointer-events: none;
}
```

I observe that the background color of the row also becomes background color of the input field if the field is disabled. If the field is not disabled the background color doesn't fill up the input field. How to prevent background color of tr to be inherited by input field when it is disabled. In a nutshell I want it to look same as when the field is enabled except a little grayed out.

Below is the HTML table that covers the scenarios.

```
<table>
 <tr>
   <td>Text Disabled</td>
   <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
   <td><input type="text" class="disabled"/></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>Text Disabled</td>
   <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
  <td><input type="text" class="disabled"/></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>Checkbox Disabled</td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" class="disabled"/></td>
   <td><input type="text" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>Checkbox Disabled</td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" class="disabled"/></td>
   <td><input type="text" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>Both Enabled</td>
   <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
   <td><input type="text" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>Both Enabled</td>
   <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
   <td><input type="text" /></td>
 </tr>
```

CSS to alternate between row background colors:

```
/* Odd Row */
tr:nth-child(2n+1) {
  background: #efef00;
}
/* Even Row */
tr:nth-child(2n) {
  background: #ffffff;
}
```

Here's jsfiddle to test this: https://jsfiddle.net/p5hcjyxx/8/

Comment: Change background color instead of opacity.

Comment: is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/p5hcjyxx/9/) what you want?

Comment: Instead of using pointer-events and opacity, why not just add the disabled attribute to the input?

Comment: Partially achieved result. Now the field is not grayed out (although disabled). It should look grayed out.

Answer (score 1):

**[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p5hcjyxx/10/)**.

That happen because of css **[opacity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity)** property.

> The opacity CSS property specifies the transparency of an element, that is, the degree to which the background behind the element is overlaid.

You could use `background-color` for example instead :

```
input.disabled {
  cursor: default;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Hope this helps.